# Getting fatal error A1008: unmatched macro nesting in masm

Tags: x86, masm

Defined a macro before the .data directive

```
    print macro char
      mov ax,char
      call WriteChar
    print endm
```

Gives the error unmatched macro nesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4chx59e.aspx) for `MACRO` has to say:

> Marks a macro block called *name* and establishes *parameter* placeholders for arguments passed when the macro is called.
>
> ```
> name MACRO [[parameter [[:REQ | :=default | :VARARG]]]]...
>    statements 
>    ENDM [[value]]
> ```

As you can see, the macro is supposed to end with `ENDM`, not `name ENDM`. And indeed, if I change `print endm` to `endm` I no longer get the "unmatched macro nesting" error.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your macro may be like:

```
 Macro Print char
       mov ax, char
       Call WriteChar
 endm
```

Your error is related to the structure of Macro.
Regards.

Comment: Nice. I ask you please to vote since the answer could helped you... :)  Regards!